# How can I disable only specific UIDs in firebase authentication?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using React native. I want to prevent logging in with a specific UID among UIDs that have anonymous login in my app.

However, Even if I try to disable anonymous login in the firebase console, it keeps logging in.

i tried like this

[image]

However, if I keep running the app, i can still be logged in. What should I do?

this is my code

```
    import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';



    useEffect(() => {
        auth()
        .signInAnonymously()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('User signed in anonymously');

        })
        .catch(error => {

            if (error.code === 'auth/operation-not-allowed') {
            console.log('Enable anonymous in your firebase console.');
            }
            console.log("error:", error);
            console.error(error);
        });
    }, []);



    function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
        setUser(user);
        if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
        return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
    }, []);
```

Comment: You are calling `signInAnonymously()` every time. So even if the user was logged out after account was disabled, a new account will be created? Or is the same user with that UID is being logged in?

Comment: @dh sorry this is my other account i did not loggout. I just want to stop specific uid login . And it comes same uid

Comment: The tokens tht Firebase uses to establish the user's identity are valid for an hour. So after disabling the user's account, it may take up to an hour for the client to notice this. Could that explain what you're seeing?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i waited over 3hours but i can still login